# "ls: not found" after running "read PATH"

Tags: shell, scripting, sh

I'm trying to write a little script to list a directory from a given variable. 
However, I can't run `ls` at all after reading my input into the variable `PATH`.

```
#!/system/bin/sh 
echo "enter directory for listing"
read "PATH"

ls "$PATH" -R > list.txt
```

This exits with:

```
ls: not found
```

...and writes nothing to `list.txt`.

Comment: Don't use `PATH` you are blowing up the `$PATH` variable which is how the shell finds commands to run. In general don't use any ALL_CAPS variables. Those are "reserved" for shell/etc. usage. Also telling us what your actual error was would have been very helpful.

Comment: Ok cheers for the heads up all I get is "ls: not found"

Comment: @JONAS402, ...and Etan already told you why, and how to fix it.

Comment: @JONAS402... rename your variable from `PATH` to `path`, and you're done. The `PATH` variable is used to determine where to look for executables; overwrite it, and the shell can no longer find `ls`.

Comment: ...so, it's nothing about using "a variable", it's about **that specific variable name**.

Comment: Yes, I figured out what error you were getting but my point was I shouldn't have had to figure it out. You should have included it as it was the point of your question.

Comment: Cheers guys, changed PATH to path and it works! Sorry, i didn't think of including the error... Will remember for the future!

Comment: I've tried to edit the question to be more useful as an example of how they should be asked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "command not found" error in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642521/getting-command-not-found-error-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The variable name `PATH` is already reserved for a different purpose: It lists all the possible locations searched to find commands not built into the shell.

`ls` is such a command. Thus, when you change the value of `PATH`, you change the way the shell tries to look for the `ls` executable; unless the new value of `PATH` includes a directory with a `ls` executable in it, any further attempts to run `ls` (or other commands not built into the shell) will fail.

Instead, use a different variable name -- ideally, including at least one lower-case character, to avoid conflict with (all-uppercase) builtins and environment variables.

---

Thus, one corrected form might be:

```
#!/system/bin/sh 
echo "enter directory for listing"
IFS= read -r path

ls -R -- "$path" > list.txt
```

Note that the `-R` is moved before the `"$path"` in this case -- while GNU systems will allow optional arguments to be after positional arguments, many older UNIX systems will only treat flags (like `-R`) as valid if they're found *before* the first non-flag/option argument.

Comment: Very good pieces of advice in here. Note that in this very case, `$path` also happens to be special in `zsh` (where it's an array tied to `$PATH` like in `csh`), so you'd get the same problem in `zsh` there (not when `zsh` is in `sh` emulation though).

Comment: Also note that even GNU `ls` won't accept options after arguments if there's a POSIXLY_CORRECT variable in the environment.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by resetting my iTerm 2.
[image]