# Parsing part of a file name to use as a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I need to get the DB name and use it as a variable from part of a file name. Currently I have it pulling in the name of the file from a **ls** command. This is what it returns:
Test-20150311-1200.sql
I need the first part of the filename up to the "-" so for this example it would be Test. How can I get just part of the file name for my variable? Below is the full script I am working on. Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash
DB_USER=x
DB_PASS=x
DB=
        for DB_GZFILE in $( ls *.sql.gz ); do
        gunzip $DB_GZFILE
            echo item: $DB_FILE unzipped
    done
        for DB_FILE in $( ls *.sql ); do    
#Use this statement to insert dump into a new server
        mysql $DB <$DB_FILE
    done    
#Use this command to insert into a server already in use
#       mysql -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS <$DB_FILE
            echo $DB_FILE inserted into database
    done
#Remove sql files used to insert into this server

#            rm $DB_FILE
#           echo $DB_FILE removed
    done

            echo restarting the mysql process .....
#       /etc/init.d/mysql restart
             echo mysql restarted
       done
```

Answer (score 3):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

```
    for DB_GZFILE in *.sql.gz; do
    for DB_FILE in *.sql; do
```

To get just the first part, use [parameter substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove the first `-` and all following characters:

```
first_part=${DB_FILE%%-*}
```

---

You should quote all your `"$vars"`, especially any whose value you get from the user or from the filesystem: you never know when you'll get a filename with a space in it. Example:

```
gunzip "$DB_GZFILE"
```

---

I'd recommend you do not use ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES: one day you'll [accidentally use `PATH=...`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310594/ls-not-found-after-running-read-path) and then wonder why your script is broken. Leave ALL_CAPS for system environment variables and shell special vars.

Comment: I've also set IFS and used set to pull out parts, such as IFS="-" set $DB_FILE, then you can pull out $1 $2, etc.

Comment: @lsd Using IFS and unquoted variable references like that will mostly work, but can fail spectacularly if the filename contains certain shell metacharacters. Using parameter substitutions (and double-quotes around variable references) as Glenn describes is better scripting practice.