# Linux Bash Script Error Handling

Tags: linux, bash, error-handling

I use bash scripts in Linux to Migrate Database output files and I was wondering of a way to handle errors when executing a Linux command in a bash script.

For example normally when I want to loop through files in a directory I will write it like this

```
# list files and grep results for .sql extension
for FILE in `ls | grep ".sql"`
do
    echo "found file: $FILE"
done
```

Which works perfectly because grep returns the file name if it has a .sql extension or returns nothing

I was wondering how to use a Linux command that returns a result or an error such as

```
ls ./*.sql
```

which returns the name of the file but if it doesn't find a file it returns the error

```
ls: ./*.sql: No such file or directory
```

Is it possible to check if a Linux command is returning an error in a bash script?

Comment: get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARS: [some day you'll use PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310594/ls-not-found-after-running-read-path) and then wonder why your script is broken.

Comment: Normally i name my variables LV_STR or LV_FILE, im not thaaat stupid to name a var PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you don't really need `ls` command here. You can just do:

```
# list files and grep results for .sql extension
for file in *.sql; do
    echo "found file: $file"
done
```

Then to avoid getting single iteration if `*.sql` files don't exist use:

```
shopt -s nullglob
# list files and grep results for .sql extension
for file in *.sql; do
    echo "found file: $file"
done
```

In general you can check `$?` after running any command to check for status of most recently executed command.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for errors with using `&&` and `||`:

```
ls ./*.sql && echo "some files exist" || echo "no such files exist"
```

You can get the error code of the last run program with checking `$?`:

```
ls ./*.sql ; echo $?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the exit code of the last run command with the `$?` variable in bash. Conventionally, `0` is returned for successful executions and `1` or higher for failed executions. As an example:

```
$ touch /root/test 
touch: cannot touch ‘/root/test’: Permission denied
$ echo $?
1
```

You can incorporate this in your bash scripts like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /root/test

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Successfully created file"
else
  echo "Could not create file"
fi
```