# Just fetch a single attrbute from a single document

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongodb-query

I need to pull the latest date from a collection on mongo db and set it in a shell script.

```
LASTDOCDATE=mongo mongo.com:27017/tracking -u user -p pw   --authenticationDatabase authdb  --eval 'db.TRACKING_DATA.find({},{datecreated :1}).limit(1).sort({datecreated:-1}).map(function (doc){ return doc.datecreated; })'

echo $LASTDOCDATE
```

This to be set but when run through the terminal produces:

```
connecting to: mongo.com:27017/tracking
Mon Jul 27 2015 16:28:08 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

have can I pull just the date attribute to be set in a shell script as a variable

Comment: I think you're just missing the [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) syntax: `last_doc_date=$(mongo ...)` -- Also, [don't use ALL_CAPS_VARS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310594/ls-not-found-after-running-read-path)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your call with the `printjson()` method of the shell in order to get an output string:

```
LASTDOCDATE=mongo mongo.com:27017/tracking -u user -p pw  \\
--authenticationDatabase authdb \\
--eval 'printjson(db.TRACKING_DATA.find({},{datecreated :1}).limit(1).sort({datecreated:-1}).map(function (doc){ return doc.datecreated; }))'
```

Or just print, while referencing the single element:

```
LASTDOCDATE=mongo mongo.com:27017/tracking -u user -p pw  \\
--authenticationDatabase authdb \\
--eval 'print(db.TRACKING_DATA.find({},{datecreated :1}).limit(1).sort({datecreated:-1}).toArray()[0].datecreated'
```

Notating the single array element, and then the property:

```js
.find({},{datecreated :1}).limit(1).sort({datecreated:-1}).toArray()[0].datecreated'
```

Or findOne() like this with [$orderby](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/):

```js
.findOne(
    { "query": {}, "$orderby": { "datecreated": 1 }},
    { "_id": 0, "datecreated": 1 }
).datecreated
```

So `.print()` or `.printjson()` depending on the output format you want. Or even `.valueOf()` on the "datecreated" to just get the timestamp value rather than the string.