# Executing scripts via CGI

Tags: apache, shell, cgi

I have two scripts which are called from a form with the get action. One of them works (calling messageserver.sh), the other doesn't. Many of these scripts are located in /usr/bin including the one that doesn't seem to be running, restartark . They all run from PuTTY without issue.

```
<form action="http://xxxxx.servegame.com/messageserver.sh" method="get">
Message to Send: <input type="text" name="message"></input><br>
<input type="submit" name="subbtn" value="Submit">
</form>


<p>
<form action="http://xxxxx.servegame.com/restartserver.sh" method="get">
Restart Server with message: <input type="text" name="restartmessage"></input><br>
<input type="submit" name="subbtn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

restartserver.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<title>Will take 10 minutes!!!</title>"
MESSAGE=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*restartmessage=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"
MESSAGE=${MESSAGE//+/ }
echo "Trying to restart server with message:<br>$MESSAGE<p>"
restartark $MESSAGE

echo "</body></html"
exit 0
```

restartark

```
#!/bin/bash
cur_date=$(date +"%m.%d.%Y-%H.%M")
echo "<p>Restart initialized! 10 minutes...  at $cur_date <br>" >> /ark2/arkstatus.txt
messageserver SERVER GOING DOWN IN 10 MINUTES $@
sleep 300
echo "Restarting in 5 minutes<br" >> /ark/arkstatus.txt
messageserver SERVER GOING DOWN FOR MAINTENANCE IN 5 MINUTES
sleep 60
messageserver SERVER GOING DOWN FOR MAINTENANCE IN 4 MINUTES
sleep 60
messageserver SERVER GOING DOWN FOR MAINTENANCE IN 3 MINUTES
sleep 60
echo "Restarting in 2 minutes<br>" >> /ark2/arkstatus.txt
messageserver SERVER GOING DOWN FOR MAINTENANCE IN 2 MINUTES
sleep 60
messageserver SERVER GOING DOWN FOR MAINTENANCE IN 1 MINUTE
sleep 60
echo "Restarting in 30 seconds<br>" >> /ark2/arkstatus.txt
messageserver SERVER GOING DOWN FOR MAINTENANCE IN 30 SECONDS
sleep 30
messageserver SERVER GOING DOWN FOR MAINTENANCE IN 15 SECONDS. LAST WARNING
sleep 15
cur_date=$(date +"%m.%d.%Y-%H.%M")
echo "Saving world... at $cur_date <br>" >> /ark2/arkstatus.txt
messageserver BRINGING SERVER DOWN NOW
sleep 3
killark
updateark
startark
```

Comment: Is the name "restartark" or "restartark.sh"?

Comment: Good catch. restartark

Comment: I think I'm missing a backtick on line 6 of restartserver.sh....

Comment: You should invoke restartark in the background so the CGI script doesn't timeout waiting for it to complete.

Comment: Would I do a `screen -dmS restarting restartark` ?

Comment: I wouldn't: `restartark $MESSAGE & disown`

Comment: 2 tips for future development: stop using ALLCAPSVARS ([you'll use PATH one day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310594/ls-not-found-after-running-read-path)); [quote all your variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) (including and especially `"$@"`).

Answer (score 0):

Missing a backtick on line 6 of restartserver.sh

Should start doing all my coding outside of nano...

Comment: Use `$(...)` instead of backticks, always.