# How to to delete a line given with a variable in sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am attempting to use `sed` to delete a line, read from user input, from a file whose name is stored in a variable. Right now all `sed` does is print the line and nothing else.

This is a code snippet of the command I am using:

```
FILE="/home/devosion/scripts/files/todo.db"
read DELETELINE
sed -e "$DELETELINE"'d' "$FILE"
```

Is there something I am missing here?

**Edit:** Switching out the `-e` option with `-i` fixed my woes!

Comment: Unless delete line is a line number it needs to be delimited. Please show the line in question and what the variable contain.

Comment: @123 I am uncertain, but im pretty sure bash's read takes user input as a string. I thought this might be a hurdle. How would I fix it to make it work? EDIT: Updated with variables.

Comment: Please show the line in question and what the variables contain.

Comment: Whoa [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/), you need need to validate your user input: if I enter `1,$`, I've just deleted every line.

Comment: @glenn jackman That it will. I have a conditional that makes sure the input is a number and within a range. The script is still in it's infancy, but since it's just for my own use I'm not too worried.

Comment: I would argue that, even for personal scripts, coding with security in mind is  an essential mindset for a programmer. Maintain high personal standards and it will become a habit for all your code.

Comment: @glenn jackman I'll keep that in mind as I continue to expand the script. For now I'm just trying to get all the primary uses for it up and running.

Comment: I just ran your 1,$ through my script and my conditional spit it out as it should, but unfortunately 1,2 was accepted and deleted my test entries.

Answer (score 6):

You need to delimit the search.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r Line

sed "/$Line/d" file
```

Will delete any line containing the typed input.

Bear in mind that sed matches on regex though and any special characters will be seen as such.
For example searching for `1*` will actually delete lines containing any number of 1's not an actual 1 and a star.

Also bear in mind that when the variable expands, it cannot contain the delimiters or the command will break or have unexpexted results.

For example if "$Line" contained "/hello" then the sed command will fail with 
`sed: -e expression #1, char 4: extra characters after command`.

You can either escape the `/` in this case or use different delimiters.

Personally i would use awk for this

```
awk -vLine="$Line" '!index($0,Line)' file
```

Which searches for an exact string and has none of the drawbacks of the sed command.

Comment: Technically your command didn't work, but thats only because it needed the -i option. In fact my command works without the delimiter now using only the -i option. So essentially sed -i "$LINE"'d' "$FILE" works just fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: With bash, you can walk through the leaning-toothpick forest: `sed "/${Line//\//\\/}/d" file` to escape any slashes in the parameter. But +1 for suggesting a string comparison function instead of regular expressions.

Comment: If you are concerned that there might be `/` characters in the variable, you can always change the delimiter sed uses, in this case using `:` as delimiter:  ```sed "\:$Line:d"```

Comment: @AlexR Yep, mentioned that `You can either escape the / in this case or use different delimiters.`

Answer (score 2):

You might have success with grep instead of sed

```
read -p "Enter a regex to remove lines: " filter
grep -v "$filter" "$file"
```

Storing in-place is a little more work:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
grep -v "$filter" "$file" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$file"
```

or, with [`sponge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sponge.1.html) (`apt install moreutils`)

```
grep -v "$filter" "$file" | sponge "$file"
```

Note: try to get out of the habit of using ALLCAPSVARS: one day you'll [accidentally use `PATH=...` and then wonder why your script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).

Comment: `sponge` is not standard. A random distro can miss it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
sed -i "${DELETELINE}d" $FILE
```

Comment: Was that tested?

Answer (score 1):

I found this, it allows for a range deletion with variables:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

lastline=$(whatever you need to do to find the last line)` //or any variation

lines="1,$lastline"

sed -i "$lines"'d' yourfile

keeps it all one util.
```