# Change path using awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, echo

Hello i want to change symlink path to real path in txt file.
First I find word "SF:" and change path.
Now i use this script but it is slow and not effective.
I think it can be changed by awk or sed command. 
Thank you in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME="new1.info"
    echo "" > $FILENAME
while read LINE
do
if [ "" != "$(echo $LINE | grep -e "^SF:")" ]
then
    echo "SF:""$(realpath $(echo $LINE | cut -d":" -f2))" >> $FILENAME
else
    echo $LINE >> $FILENAME
fi
done < total.info
```

I have big txt file, so I want to find "SF:" and change line from something like this:

```
SF:/home/ects/svn/moduleTests/ctest/tests/moduletests/base/tmp/src/base64.cpp
```

To this:

```
SF:/home/ects/svn/moduleTests/ctest/src/base/base64.cpp
```

Comment: Hello @george123. Welcome to SO. Have you made some reasearches yet?
Could you please show us what you have already tried? Also consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try `sed -i 's/^SF://'` (or, `sed -i '' 's/^SF://'` if you are on Mac) if all you want is to remove `SF:` at the start of each line

Comment: make a small example, what you have, and what do you want to get. we don't know what text in your `$LINE`

Comment: I went looking for a solution for exactly the same problem, and I do mean exactly. I assume you're doing this because the SonarTS plugin in SonarQube doesn't handle symlinks?

Comment: No, it was related to the LCOV code coverage tool, but this tool doesn't handle symlinks too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, I'd write

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" == "SF:"* ]]; then
        line="SF:$(realpath "${line#SF:}")"
    fi
    echo "$line"
done < total.info > new1.info
```

Things to note:

- [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells), every time.
- don't use ALLCAPS varnames, it will [bite you eventually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552)
- note the output redirection has been moved to the outside of the while loop, just like the input redirection
- `IFS= read -r line` is the way to read lines from the file exactly.

I don't know if this will be any faster: bash can be quite slow, particular for `while read` loops over big files. You could try another language:

```
perl -MCwd=abs_path -pe 's/^SF:\K(.*)/ abs_path($1) /e' total.info > new1.info
```

Comment: @george123, for your future questions, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers