# reuse virtual files in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

What I am trying to do is run a bash script that looks somewhat like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

only1=$(comm -23 $1 $2 | wc -l)
only2=$(comm -13 $1 $2 | wc -l)
common=$(comm -12 $1 $2 | wc -l)

echo -e "${only1} only in $1"
echo -e "${only2} only in $2"
echo -e "${common} in both"
```

If I execute the script as `script.sh file1 file2` it works fine. However, if I use it as `script.sh <(grep 'foo' file1) <(grep 'foo' file2)` it fails because the virtual files of the kind `dev/fd/62` are only available for the first command (`only1` in the script). The output is:

```
262 only in /dev/fd/63
0 only in /dev/fd/62
0 in both
```

Is there a way to make these virtual files available to all of the commands in the script?

Comment: You should supply some test data. It is not clear if `262 only in /dev/fd/63` or `0 only in /dev/fd/62` is expected or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the first invocation of `comm` will read to the end of both input files.

As you'd like to be able to provide pipes as the input (instead of a "*real* file), you'll need read the inputs once only, and then provide that as input to the subsequent commands... With pipes, as soon as data is read, it's gone and isn't coming back.

For example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -eu

# cleanup temporary files on exit
trap 'rm ${TMP_FILE1:-} ${TMP_FILE2:-}' EXIT

TMP_FILE1=$(mktemp)
cat < $1 > $TMP_FILE1

TMP_FILE2=$(mktemp)
cat < $2 > $TMP_FILE2

only1=$(comm -23 $TMP_FILE1 $TMP_FILE2 | wc -l)
only2=$(comm -13 $TMP_FILE1 $TMP_FILE2 | wc -l)
common=$(comm -12 $TMP_FILE1 $TMP_FILE2 | wc -l)

echo -e "${only1} only in $1"
echo -e "${only2} only in $2"
echo -e "${common} in both"
```

If your files are small enough, then you can get away with reading them into variables:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -eu

FILE1=$( < $1 )
FILE2=$( < $2 )

only1=$(comm -23 <( echo "$FILE1" ) <( echo "$FILE2" ) | wc -l)
only2=$(comm -13 <( echo "$FILE1" ) <( echo "$FILE2" ) | wc -l)
common=$(comm -12 <( echo "$FILE1" ) <( echo "$FILE2" ) | wc -l)

echo -e "${only1} only in $1"
echo -e "${only2} only in $2"
echo -e "${common} in both"
```

---

Please also note that `comm` only works on ***sorted*** data... which means you probably want to use `sort` on the inputs, unless you are fully aware of the consequences of using unsorted inputs.

```sh
sort < $1 > $TMP_FILE1
```

```sh
FILE1=$( sort < $1 )
```

Comment: I would just store the content in variables, not files: `dataA=$(< "$1" )` and then use process substitutions for the comm commands: `only1=$( comm -23 <(echo "$dataA") <(echo "$dataB") | wc -l )`

Comment: In case the script is terminated early, it's a good idea to clean up the temp files in a trap: near the beginning of the code add `cleanup() { rm -f "$TMP_FILE1" "$TMP_FILE2"; }` and then `trap cleanup EXIT`

Comment: Avoid using ALLCAPS variable names: you can [shoot yourself in the foot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552)