# Python include shell path filename

Tags: python, shell, path, command

Here is my code in shell and I include python command:

```
for file in `ls $FOLDER`
do
    echo "$file"
    var=`python -c "from Bio import SeqIO, SeqUtils; import os; rec = SeqIO.read("**$FOLDER/$file**", 'fasta'); SeqUtils.xGC_skew(rec.seq, 220000)" `
done
```

And I do not know how to make python recognize my file name

Comment: Are you getting any error? If yes, please add the error output in the question.

Comment: Here is the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/criuser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 671, in read
    raise ValueError("More than one record found

Comment: It is like it does not see my file and I do not know how to tell it '$FOLDER/$file' in a python way

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the double quotes in the python code:

```shell
for file in `ls $FOLDER`
do
    echo "$file"
    var=`python -c "from Bio import SeqIO, SeqUtils; import os; rec = SeqIO.read(\"$FOLDER/$file\", 'fasta'); SeqUtils.xGC_skew(rec.seq, 220000)" `
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some common shell mistakes:

- [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use

  ```sh
  for file in "$FOLDER"/*; ...
  ```
- Use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` `` -- easier to read, easier to nest. [Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)
- Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then [wonder why your script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).