# command not found in awk sentence

Tags: shell, awk

I have this problem with this awk, that it works but I get the command not found error

```
for line in $(cat ${FILE_LIST_PROCES}); do 
    
    ARCHIVO=$line
    echo "[`date '+DATE: %m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'`] - Validando script: "$ARCHIVO
    if [ ! -f $ARCHIVO ]; then
            echo "[`date '+DATE: %m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'`] - ERROR -"
        exit ${ARCHIVO_NO_ENCONTRADO}
    else
        `gawk '{
            if (/GRANT/||/REVOKE/) 
                if (/EXECUTE/||/REFERENCES/||/TRIGGER/||/ALL PRIVILEGES/) 
                    print "1";
                else{
                    I=0;
                    while (I<=NF){
                        if ($I == "TO")
                            if ($++I !~ /^[^uU][0-9]{6};?$/)    
                                print "1";
                        I++
                    }
                }
            }' "$ARCHIVO"`
            if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then
                $ARCHIVO >> $FILE_LIST_TMP  
            else 
                echo "[`date '+DATE: %m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'`] - ERROR - "
                mv $ARCHIVO $FILE_ERRORES
            fi                         
    fi
done
```

with the following error when I echo 1, I don't understand what is the problem

```
./build.sh: line 80: 1: command not found
```

Comment: [Check your script](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: [How can I read a file line-by-line?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then [wonder why your script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).

Comment: I'm just adding a awk to a script that it's not mine so well thanks for the advice...

Answer (score 0):

Backticks are  [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) -- the contents of the backticks are executed in a subshell, and the shell replace the command substitution with the output. This is why `echo "Right now it is $(date)"` works as you expect.

If you do this:

```sh
echo before
`date`
echo after
```

Then, after the command substitution, the shell will try to run this:

```sh
echo before
Thu Jun 25 10:30:12 EDT 2020
echo after
```

And you see some error like `Thu: command not found`

#### TL;DR

You don't put backticks around *every* external command.

---

Also, prefer the `$(...)` form of command substitution -- it's easier to see and easier to nest.

Comment: I don't fully understand your answer I get the error after the gawk part

Comment: What is the output of that gawk command? What would happen if you attempted to execute that output as bash commands?

Comment: the output is 1, it works fine in the command line, but it is the only thing that I have added (also the if following them) and the error comes with the echo result so 1 or whatever I put in echo

Comment: Think about why you have surrounded the gawk command with backticks.

Comment: I tried with the $(...)  still I have the same error :/

Comment: You don't want to execute **the output of gawk**. You just want to display it, right? Don't put the gawk command inside backticks *or* $(...).

Comment: no, I need the exit for the if, now I put the $? because you know I needed to go on with my life, but I need to catch the output

Comment: This is the first time you have said that you need to capture the output.

Answer (score 0):

this somehow fix it:

```
 for line in $(cat ${FILE_LIST_PROCES}); do 
        
        ARCHIVO=$line
        echo "[`date '+DATE: %m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'`] - Validando script: "$ARCHIVO
        if [ ! -f $ARCHIVO ]; then
                echo "[date '+DATE: %m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'] - ERROR - archivo " ${ARCHIVO} " no encontrado"
            exit ${ARCHIVO_NO_ENCONTRADO}
        else
            iResult=`gawk '{
                if (/GRANT/||/REVOKE/) 
                    if (/EXECUTE/||/REFERENCES/||/TRIGGER/||/ALL PRIVILEGES/) 
                        print "1";
                    else{
                        I=0;
                        while (I<=NF){
                            if ($I == "TO")
                                if ($++I !~ /^[^uU][0-9]{6};?$/)    
                                    print "1";
                            I++
                        }
                    }
                }' "$ARCHIVO"`
                for i in $iResult
                do  
                    if [ $i -ne 0 ]; then
                    echo "[`date '+DATE: %m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'`] - ERROR - Archivo con sentencia erronea"
                    exit ${ARCHIVO_NO_ENCONTRADO}
                    fi
                done                    
        fi
    done
```