# AWK print unexpected newline or end of string inside shell

Tags: unix, awk

I have a shell script which is trying to trim a file from end of the line but I always get some error.

Shell Script:

```sh
AWK_EXPRESSION='{if(length>'"$RANGE1"'){ print substr('"$0 "',0, length-'"$RANGE2"'}) } else { print '"$0 "'} }'

for report in ${ACTUAL_TARGET_FOLDER}/* ; do
  awk $AWK_EXPRESSION $report > $target_file
done
```

If I trigger the AWK command, I get `unexpected newline or end of string` near print.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is $0 supposed to be replaced by the shell or is the intention to pass it to awk as $0?

Comment: Related: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @Joni $0 the line read from the file...

Comment: Are you aware this overwrites the target file for every report?

Comment: Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes as you have several quoting bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend writing the AWK program using AWK variables instead of interpolating variables into it from the shell. You can pass variable into awk on the command line using the `-v` command line option.

Also, awk permits using white space to make the program readable, just like other programming languages. Like this:

```sh
AWK_EXPRESSION='{
  if (length > RANGE1) {
    print substr($0, 1, length-RANGE2)
  } else {
    print
  }
}'

for report in "${ACTUAL_TARGET_FOLDER}"/* ; do
  awk -v RANGE1="$RANGE1" -v RANGE2="$RANGE2" "$AWK_EXPRESSION" "$report" > "$target_file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks @joni this helped and worked for me... was breaking my head whole day today on this.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to store the awk body in a shell variable? Just use awk and the `-v` option to pass a shell value into an awk variable:

```sh
awk -v range1="$RANGE1" -v range2="$RANGE2" '{
    if (length > range1) {
        print substr($0,0, length-range2)
    } else { 
        print 
    }
}' "$ACTUAL_TARGET_FOLDER"/* > "$target_file"
```

Add a few newlines to help readability.

Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then [wonder why your script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).

Unquoted variables are subject to [word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and [glob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) expansion. Use double quotes for all your variables unless you know what specific side-effect you want to use.

Comment: thanks @glenn used what Joni have suggested and your insight also helped... Thanks!