# Command substitution with variables gives command not found?

Tags: bash

I'm having a BASH script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PATH=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)

YAML=$(envsubst < ${PATH}/test.yml)

echo "${YAML}"
```

It results:

```
./test.sh: line 5: envsubst: command not found
```

I see that having a variable inside command substitution causes such error.
If I'm not using any:

```
YAML=$(envsubst < ./test.yml)
```

Then I'm having an expected successful script execution.

I've tried different syntax using quotes all over the place, but nothing helped.

**How do I successfully use variable inside command substitution?**

Bash version:

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

**UPDATE**: A duplicate question. Found an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5642584/5935309

Comment: What is the advantage of `PATH=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]"}" && pwd)` over `PATH=$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]")`?

Comment: Don't put commands in variables. It's a bad habit that frequently results in hard-to-debug errors. Write a function instead.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann, if my case you get absolute path, where in your case you get relative path like ``./some-dir``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing `PATH`, which is used by Bash internally to define where to look for programs (and in which order).

You changed `PATH` to only contain the current working dir, and that's not where `envsubst` is located.

The solution is to use something different than `PATH`, like `FILE_PATH`.