# After EOF command didn't run

Tags: bash, shell

**I am working on two servers one is oracle database and another is linux , first of all i exported path of oracle server and later i want to process the output and it is showing bash command not found error , I tried with exporting bash profile too Below is what i  have done as far :**

```
#!/bin/bash
export ORACLE_HOME=/Oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.2/db_1 
export PATH=/Oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.2/db_1/bin:.
sqlplus system@xe/oracle123 << EOF >home/cron.log
@/home/test.sql > /home/zoutput/test.txt
EOF

echo "This is test"
```

**error**: *syntax error near unexpected token `"This is test"'*

```
#!/bin/bash
export ORACLE_HOME=/Oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.2/db_1 
export PATH=/Oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.2/db_1/bin:.
sqlplus system@xe/oracle123 << EOF >home/cron.log
@/home/test.sql > /home/zoutput/test.txt
EOF

echo("This is test")
cut -c-3 /Backend/home/zoutput/test.txt|sort |uniq 
>/Backend/home/zoutput/test2.txt
```

**ERROR**
  *cut*,*sort*,*uniq* command not found

Comment: What do you think your script should do?

Comment: Did you mean to trash the pre-existing path completely?

Comment: After EOF command clearly DID run as it produced a syntax error. Run your script through shellcheck (e.g. http://shellcheck.net), fix the errors and then let us know if you still have questions.

Comment: The main problem is after EOF any linux command it is not taking properly , what the heck happend with EOF i don't know @MadPhysicist

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642521/command-not-found-error-in-bash-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [command not found error in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642521/command-not-found-error-in-bash-script)

Comment: I didn't found out any solution from that question @tripleee

Comment: i didn't find any solution and it is as duplicate @Shawn

Comment: When you override `PATH` like that, you basically disable all external commands. The system directories `/bin`, `/usr/bin` etc need to be on your `PATH` in order for e.g. `cat` or `ls` to work. (`echo` is a bad example because it's a shell builtin; but of course, as the answer you got already states, your syntax is horribly wrong.)

Comment: Look at your code closer, then. See where you set `PATH`?

Comment: Can i export a new path as export $PATH =/home/zoutput/ for below lines (*to_make_use_of_cut*)  appending new path after EOF (can i do that ?) @Shawn

Comment: Why are you *replacing* the path at all?

Comment: i need to communicate with different server so i need to set another path for that @Shawn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use echo without parentheses!

```
echo "This is test"
```

Comment: cut -c-3 /home/zoutput/test.txt|sort |uniq >/home/zoutput/test2.txt    (*after that line it is showing cut command not found* , I have a next cut_line command after that , soley this command is working but inside here it is not working)